# TouchPad not storing during windows 10 installation

Tags: operating-systems

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04. And now I would like to get windows 10. I downloaded the iso and mounted on a USB. When I boot from it, during the windows 10 installation process, my TouchPad is not working. It worked fine when I was running Ubuntu. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to inject the touchpad drivers into the Windows 10 image you are trying to install. This blog post has a good walkthrough (performed on a Windows 10 release candidate in 2014):

[Inject Drivers to Windows 10 Install Media](https://ndswanson.wordpress.com/2014/10/24/inject-drivers-to-windows-10-install-media/)

The simpler solution would be to plug in a mouse to a USB port for the install. Then when Windows 10 is installed it should download the drivers for the touchpad.

Comment: I'm proceeding with a mouse, and after the installation, what should be done?

Comment: Once the install is done and the machine is connected to the Internet it should pull the drivers for the touchpad down automatically. If it doesn't, then you will need to download the driver from the laptop manufacturer's website (I assume this is a laptop). If it is a standalone touchpad then you will need to download the driver from the touchpad manufacturer's website.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the drivers were not downloaded automatically. I had to manually download the drivers from manufacturers website.